# Javascript object instance property getting set unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, function-constructor

I have the following code:

```
function Foo() {
    Foo.prototype.test = 0;
}

Foo.prototype.incTest = function() {
    Foo.prototype.test++;
};

Foo.prototype.getTest = function(name) {
    console.log(name +" this: " + this.test + " proto: " + Foo.prototype.test);
};

var bar = new Foo();
var baz = new Foo();

bar.getTest('bar');
bar.incTest();
bar.getTest('bar');

baz.incTest();
bar.getTest('bar');
baz.getTest('baz');
```

predictably the output is:

```
bar this: 0 proto: 0
bar this: 1 proto: 1 
bar this: 2 proto: 2 
baz this: 2 proto: 2
```

Now I try to take advantage of `this` looking up the prototype chain, and change `incTest` to :

```
Foo.prototype.incTest = function() {
    this.test++;
};
```

This gives me completely different output!

```
bar this: 0 proto: 0 
bar this: 1 proto: 0 
bar this: 1 proto: 0 
baz this: 1 proto: 0
```

Shouldn't `this.test` reference the Foo prototype property? What exactly is going on here?

EDIT:

Furthermore, changing the line to `Foo.prototype.test = this.test++;` also produces the second output, and I'm not sure why.

EDIT 2:

Solution to first edit was postfix vs. prefix. Prefix increment produces first output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First case:**

You were incrementing only the prototype variable, which will be shared by all the instances of the prototype object.

*The important thing to be noted here is*, when you access the `test` with `this.test` in the first case, JavaScript tries to find the `test` in `this` (current object). It fails to find it and it goes up the ladder in the prototype chain. It finds `test` in the `Foo.prototype` and returns that value. That is why you were getting same values for `this.test` and `Foo.prototype.test`.

**Second case:**

You were incrementing `this.test`. `this.test++` can be understood like this

```
this.test = this.test + 1
```

Now, it fetches the value of `test` from the pototype chain (`Foo.prototype.test` will be used, which is 0), adds 1 to it and stores that result in the `test` member of the current object. So, you are creating a new member in `this` called `test`. That is why the value of it is different from `Foo.prototype.test`.

You can confirm this by adding one more method, like this

```
Foo.prototype.deleteTest = function () {
    delete this.test;
}

...
...
bar.deleteTest();
bar.getTest('bar');
```

Now `bar.getTest` will print `0`, because we deleted the `test` from `this`, with `deleteTest()`. So, it will go up the ladder and find the `test` in `Foo.prototype`, which is 0.

Comment: I see. It didn't dawn on my that `this.test++` is equivalent to `this.test = this.test + 1`. The output makes sense if viewed this way. Thanks!

Comment: a further question. `Foo.prototype.test = (this.test++)` produces the second output... why?

Comment: @moesef because, you are incrmenting `this.test` and assigning the value before incrementing to `Foo.prototype.test`. (*Remember:* var++ is postfix operator). So, the `Food.prototype.test`'s value will be one less. Try `Foo.prototype.test = ++this.test;`, you ll be able to understand the difference :)

Comment: yea. just tried that. made the difference that I was expecting. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

The `this` will reference the current instance of the function, not the prototype.

Comment: right. but if the current instance does not have the property `test`, shouldn't it resolve to the prototype's `test`? otherwise, `this.test` would be `undefined` and incrementing `undefined` gives `NaN`

Comment: The prototype has the property, so all of the instances inherit the property but they have their own instance.

Comment: I don't believe that is true. Otherwise the first output wouldn't happen. (ie. changing the prototype's test property value wouldn't change the object's test property)

Comment: Before the object has its own instance it automatically uses the prototype's instance. Once you set its own instance, it uses it going forwards.